# How can I ensure my middleware logic executes only once per session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-core-middleware

I have implemented a middleware in my mvc web application that retrieves all user data from the database and sets it in the session object.
However, since the middleware is called on each HTTP session,
 I want to ensure that this logic executes only once per session.
Here is my current implementation:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{

    if (context.Session.Get("sessionWasInitialized") != null)
    {
        // Session was initialized, finish this task
        await _next(context);
        return;
    }

    // This Key will make sure that the session was initialized once per session
    context.Session.SetString("sessionWasInitialized", "true");

    // Get user data from DB and set the Session object...
    //    .........
    //
    await _next(context);
}
```

While this approach seems to work, **I'm wondering if there is a more efficient or elegant way to achieve the same behavior**. I would appreciate any suggestions or alternative approaches to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually from your code, I think check if the session is null via session key is reasonable and should work effectively.

If the session in your project only for this situation, you can use:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!context.Session.Keys.Any())
    {
        // Get user data from DB and set the Session object...
        //    .........
        //
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

This approach reduces the overhead of checking for a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

To detect repeated calls programmatically and warn if it's detected will be the more efficient and elegant solution. :-)

Generally you need to determine the unique session identifier, maintain the session list and check the session is already enlisted.